# Can't update(uninstall/install) pm2 version 0.7.8

Tags: node.js, pm2

Im stuck with upgrade pm2 to latest version from `0.7.8` to `1.1.3`

Official [documentation](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/update-pm2/) says that it simply done with `npm install pm2 -g` and `pm2 update` but actually my current version of `pm2(0.7.8)` don't have update command it is new feature

i also tried to `uninstall/install` option by [this](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/1466) tutorial but it didn't not removing anything and i don't want to manually remove some `/usr/` or `/lib` folders to not harm something as suggesting in that article last comment

**So my question:** is there present some normal way to remove pm2(version 0.7.8) ? some native way

*i also not able to find old documentation for pm2 to find there remove or upgrade steps ...*

Comment: @Ziki but isn't it updating `npm` ? i need to update `pm2` instead. I tried instead `npm install -g pm2@latest` the response was `/usr/local/bin/pm2 -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2` `pm2@1.1.3`, but after typing `pm2 -V` i stll see same version `0.7.8`

Comment: My mistage.. `npm install -g pm2@latest`. maybe it's because you are in a folder that have locally node_module pm2

Comment: @Ziki no i have tried it also at different location where no node_modules present, it not helps

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After long research i did not find any better way then delete files manually and install it as has been suggested [here](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/1466)

My runned commands:

```
# Remove part
rm /usr/bin/pm2
rm -r /usr/local/lib/node_modules
rm -r /root/.pm2/
# Server reboot
reboot
# Install
npm install pm2 -g
```

after this i have now `pm2` at `1.1.3` version and all works well